# How to change environmental variable permanently?

Tags: bash, python, environment-variables

I am trying to use third party packages in Python. To import all the modules I need to update `PYTHONPATH`. I read several blogs on it but still I have following questions unanswered.

1. Is `sys.path` & `PYTHONPATH` are same things ? (probably not)
2. How to see current value of `PYTHONPATH` (which is something called environmental variable) ?
3. How to update `PYTHONPATH` permenently ?

I know I can do `sys.path.append('/<PATH>')`, but that updates `sys.path` until you do not exit the Python interpreter.

```
export `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/<PATH>
```

(I know this but I do not know what is current $PYTHONPATH)

How do I update `PYTHONPATH` permanently ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not into phython, but it seems that the sys.path variable is just an accessor to the system-wide PYTHONPATH variable. If you modify it, the PYTHONPATH variable won't be changed, only the sys.path python variable.
2. Type into your command prompt: `echo $PYTHONPATH` If it shows nothing, PYTHONPATH isn't set at all.
3. Add that `export ...` line at the end of the .bashrc file of the concerning user's home directory and restart your shell.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sys.path` contains paths from `PYTHONPATH` environment variable plus the folder the script was started from. See more info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)
2. `echo $PYTHONPATH` in a terminal or `import os; print os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` (from Python, will work if such a variable was defined)
3. To set an environment variable for all applications, read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables). Add this `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/some/package` to `~/.pam_environment` file.